# Why does Unity show dark regions on a model with animation created using Blender?

Tags: unity, blender

I sculpted a model in blender, and I want to import that to Unity. When I import just the model(without animation), Unity shows as is. However, when I attach armature to the body and automatically assign  weights to it with the intention of creating an animation, Unity import shows dark regions all over the model. All the face normals look fine. I am not sure what the issue is.

Model in Blender:
[image: Model in Blender:]

Weights:
[image: Weights]

Dark patches in Unity:
[image: Dark patches in Unity]

Comment: Are the normals flipped? In Blender, go into Object mode and use Shift-N to recalculate normals.

Comment: I have checked the normals, all are pointed outwards and just to be sure I recalculated them yet it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Did you check the material?

Comment: Yes, it does not have any material assigned while importing to unity. I think that it might be a problem with normals, but in blender the they look fine.

Comment: What happens if you drag it into a scene and add a material in Unity?